# Django not loading admin css - 'static' settings

Tags: python, css, django

I am new in Django, just studying docs.djangoproject tutorial. My admin page doesn't display css styles, so I suppose I have not set "static" paths correctly. Working on home PC as a server with Windows OS.

Here are some code from the files:

settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    #Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    #url(r'^$', 'polysite.views.home', name='home'),
    #url(r'^polysite/', include('polysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: `DEBUG=True`? correct?

Comment: Also, are you running it using any webserver? or just on your localhost using the development web server included in django?

Comment: DEBUG=True and running on localhost (Windows)

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you did?  I tried to reproduce your error but couldn't on Windows 7.  I installed django 1.5.5, created a new project, uncommented the relevant admin lines (in INSTALLED_APPS and urls.py) and set up a basic sqlite db.  Using `manage.py runserver` I was able to see CSS in chrome off the local dev server.

Comment: How did you set up a basic sqlite db? I use inner python db (manage.py syncdb)